# Material UI Styles

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Every time I run `npm start` in vscode I get weird material UI errors like

```
Module parse failed: D:\Websites\rugprints\rugprints\node_modules\@mui\material\node\styles\createTransitions.js Unexpected token (58:40)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (58:40)
 @ ./~/@mui/material/node/styles/index.js 215:25-55

webpackHotDevClient.js:233 Error in ./~/@mui/system/colorManipulator.js
Module parse failed: D:\Websites\rugprints\rugprints\node_modules\@mui\system\colorManipulator.js Unexpected token (216:67)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (216:67)
 @ ./~/@mui/system/index.js 444:24-53

webpackHotDevClient.js:233 Error in ./~/@mui/material/node/ButtonBase/TouchRipple.js
Module parse failed: D:\Websites\rugprints\rugprints\node_modules\@mui\material\node\ButtonBase\TouchRipple.js Unexpected token (257:46)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (257:46)
 @ ./~/@mui/material/node/ButtonBase/ButtonBase.js 34:42-66

webpackHotDevClient.js:233 Error in ./~/@mui/material/node/Paper/Paper.js
Module parse failed: D:\Websites\rugprints\rugprints\node_modules\@mui\material\node\Paper\Paper.js Unexpected token (47:38)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (47:38)
 @ ./~/@mui/material/node/Paper/index.js 24:36-54

webpackHotDevClient.js:233 Error in ./~/@mui/material/node/Grow/Grow.js
Module parse failed: D:\Websites\rugprints\rugprints\node_modules\@mui\material\node\Grow\Grow.js Unexpected token (37:35)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (37:35)
 @ ./~/@mui/material/node/Grow/index.js 15:35-52
```

and it has just begun doing this

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Did you upgrade from material ui v4 to v5?

Comment: I upgraded for Material UI v4 to v5

Comment: what npm version u using?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with these weird errors. I had created my project using create-react-app, and somehow my package.json was like this:

```
"react-scripts": "^0.9.5"
```

I manually changed this line to:

```
"react-scripts": "^4.0.3"
```

Then run:

```
npm install
```

to install the new version
The errors were gone!

Comment: This is what got my project running. The template package.json is older than my grandma...

Answer (score 0):

When upgrading from mui v4 to mui v5, you need to use the following:

index.js

```
import { StyledEngineProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";

//...

ReactDOM.render(
      <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst> //<<--- Here
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
              <App />
        </ThemeProvider>
      </StyledEngineProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

v5 uses a new styling engine, and you need to insert StyledEngineProvider to support the v4 one.

Answer (score 0):

change react-scripts version in package.json to "react-scripts": "^4.0.3" . create-react-app is not pulling the correct version that's why you are facing this issue.